# Pressing tab moves to one after the next control

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing a simple wpf c# application for handling data in a database. A function that dynamically generates a `ComboBox` and a `Textbox` is executed from the *Main* `TextBox` when the tab-key is pressed down. Theoretically, it is supposed to switch focus to the next control, i.e. the newly generated `ComboBox`. Instead, when executed it moves to the latter generated `TextBox`. below is the code I have implemented.

### Code Used:

```
private void Add_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
{
    // insert generation code here
}
```

The above function is called when tab is pressed through this:

```
private void MainTextbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.Tab)
    {
        Add_PreviewMouseDown(null, null);
    }
}
```

### Possible Reasons:

I think the issue might be with the time delay between the tab-key down and the process of creating the controls. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to focus a specific control or what is your issue? Please remember to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue when asking a question.

Comment: Set the focus on the added control directly and use e.Handled = true to prevent the normal handling of the Tab key.  Do move the "generation code" into a separate method, one that returns a reference to the added control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of writing your own key-handler, try overriding the existing one:

```
using System.Windows.Input;

//Later on:
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
     base.OnKeyDown(e);
     if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Tab)
     {
          //Handle the tab key
     }
}
```

You may, or may not need the base.OnKeyDown(e); cause that is probably what causes the default behavior of tab: Namely to shift focus to the next UI element in you application eg. the next textbox.

You could therefore try something like:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Key != System.Windows.Input.Key.Tab)
     {
          base.OnKeyDown(e); //Default behavior for all other keys
     }else{
          //Custom behavior for the tab key
     }
}
```

I hope this helps :-)